# How to set a custom field name for an invisible signature field - pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

How to set a custom field name for an invisible signature field via pdf box

[image]

I want to change from **Signature1 (invisible signature)** to **Foo**

Comment: before signing or after signing? (Spoiler: it's not possible after signing, obviously)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr yes before signing or we can say during signing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code after the `document.addSignature()` call:

```
document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("Signature1").setPartialName("Foo");
```

or

```
for (PDSignatureField signatureField : signatureFields)
{
    if ("Signature1".equals(signatureField.getPartialName()))
    {
        signatureField.setPartialName("Foo");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, I got idea when I look `PDSignatureField` constructor and it call `setPartialName` of PDField. So Root element `Catalog` has `AcroForm` which has `Fields` and field has T  :) . As you respond, I am going to accept your answer

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor do you have success set field name ? i have try PDSignatureField signatureField = new PDSignatureField(acroFormField); signatureField.setPartialName("name"); not success in createVisualSignatureTemplate()